# Showing attribute table in QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, attribute-table, pyqgis-3

I'm trying to develop a plugin which grabs a layer from the project and shows its attribute table in a `tableView`. My code is as follows:

```py
def getVectorLayer(self):
    layer = None
    layername = self.dlg.CBLayerInputs.currentText()
    for lyr in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
        if lyr.name == layername:
            layer = lyr
            self.dlg.tableView.QgsAttributeTableView(layer)
            break
        return layer
```

However, I do not get any error - the code compiles correctly without error, but no attribute table information is shown in the table view.

Answer (score 1):

[QgsAttributeTableView](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsAttributeTableModel.html#a42ca0669fdd35da9fd999c1733a963a3) doesn't receive an object of type **QgsVectorLayer**

I add a small Snippet to get what you want, it is more complex than it seems.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
vector_layer_cache = QgsVectorLayerCache(layer, 10000)
attribute_table_model = QgsAttributeTableModel(vector_layer_cache)
attribute_table_model.loadLayer()

attribute_table_filter_model = QgsAttributeTableFilterModel(canvas, attribute_table_model)
attribute_table_view = QgsAttributeTableView()
attribute_table_view.setModel(attribute_table_filter_model)

attribute_table_view.show()
```

Based on this [example](https://github.com/webgeodatavore/pyqgis-samples/blob/master/gui/qgis-sample-QgsAttributeTableView.py).

Comment: Not sure how that shows up in the "tableView" of my dialogue box though which is set to `self.dlg.tableView`

Comment: `attribute_table_view` is in your case `self.dlg.tableView`. QgsAttributeTableView inherits from QTableView

Comment: Ok thanks - I will try this - I'm still a little confused however.